# Why my confusion matrix has 7 elements, while I trianed 6 classes?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I classified my data into 6 classes. But the confusion matrix has 7 elements. Why? Which one is the extra class and is that the unable-to-classify class? And I am really confused how to read this matrix. If the rows are the actual values, and the columns are the predicted values, why every row has 7 values? Isn't the confusion matrix is a 2-D table? I could really use more help to interpret this .errorMatrix().
Here is the code,thanks.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/44a460e8f13c73dc10edf52d4c53ec2e